# Custom underline effect, other than creating a background image for it

Tags: css

is there a better way to create this style of "underline" through CSS, other than creating a background image for it?

To be clear, I'm only interested in the "duplicated line" effect, a thicker and shorter line sitting directly atop a thinner and longer line of a different color. Thanks!

[image: Custome underline]

Comment: make use of pseudo elements

Comment: Post the code you have so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pseudo elements here, i.e. `:before` and `:after`. Here, what am doing is, using an `h1` element which am displaying it as `inline-block`. Later, we need to use CSS positioning to set both the bottom borders in place, as the borders are smaller than your element.

Later, again by using CSS positioning, we position the small `border` on top of the bigger one. Note that am using `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` to position the border in horizontally center.

Make sure you don't miss out the `z-index` as it is important to use here, else the other border will render on top of the smaller one.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Varela Round;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #401f1c;
  margin: 40px; /* not required, only for demo purpose */
}

h1 span {
  color: #efcc4c;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h1:before {
  bottom: -11px;
  width: 40px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #efcc4c;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1:after {
  width: 80%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Our <span>Services</span></h1>
```

Edit: Refactored my code and making the demo more precisee.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="text">
  <span>our</span>
  Services
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text{
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:25px;
  color:red;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.text::after,
.text::before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:5px;
  height:0px;
}

.text::before{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.text::after{
  width:50%;
  border:2px solid red;
  bottom:-6px;
}

.text span{
  color:#000000;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/7vwn29s9/1/)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

I always create "divider", like:

```
<div class='divider'>
    <div class='divi-1'></div>
    <div class='divi-2'></div>
    <div class='divi-3'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divider{
    padding-top:15px; //or other
    text-align:center;
    display:block; // or column in bootstrap like col-md-12
}

.divider .divi-1{
    display:inline-block;
    height:2px; //or other
    width:50px; // or other
    background:#e5e5e5;
.

.divider .divi-2{
    display:inline-block;
    height:2px;
    width:50px;
    background:#000000;
}
.divider .divi-1{
    display:inline-block;
    height:2px; //or other
    width:50px; // or other
    background:#e5e5e5;
}
```

And that's it. You can also use vertical-align for inline-block so You have some more options to move lines verticaly ... and also it's in the flow so You know what size it have and can be sure that other elements won't overlap it.